# FrameLabel missing when rotated

Tags: plotting, frame

I am using Mathematica 10.0 on Windows 8.1. When I save the following simple plot, the FrameLabel does not appear if I rotate the FrameLabel by $-90^o$. If I do not rotate it, the saved plot shows the FrameLabel.

```
 P = 
   Plot[Exp[-x^2], {x, -π, π}, 
     Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
     FrameLabel -> {"x", Rotate["ψ(x)", -90 Degree]}, 
     ImageSize -> 250]
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "sample.pdf", P]
```

How can this be corrected?

Comment: What OS are you on, for completeness?

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1.

Comment: I do not have that issue on mma 11.2 @win 10. Try to enforce image padding and see what happens e.g. `Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "sample.pdf", 
 Show[P, ImagePadding -> {{50, 20}, {20, 20}}]]`

Comment: @ercegovac, Thanks. But ImagePadding is also not working.

Comment: Did you try export to some other format?

Comment: Yes. It does work for JPEG. But the Image quality is not good. It looks as if drawn by hand.